# Add custom header and footer Lotus Notes for printable form

Tags: lotus-domino, lotus

It's easy to add headers and footers to a form , using the form properties, but the available options are all text based.

Is there a way to add a Graphic to the Header and Footer without using third party products like Swing ?

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't. As you already found out, there are third party tools to do this (e.g. NotesToPaper from Softvision), but there is no way to do it with standard Notes options

Comment: Yes, seems like 3rd Party is the only way, unless someone has some examples how to use the C Api ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the footer and header in your form, and [always hide them except when printing](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/Rnext/help6_designer.nsf/89d3962efd85426f85256b870069c0aa/ce5b48db0cefddbe85256c54004b70b3?OpenDocument).

Comment: The question was if it's possible to add pictures/graphics to header or footer...

Comment: The idea is to put headers & footers _**in**_ the form, like any other paragraph of the form (except, obv. one at the top and one at the bottom ;-) and **_not_** in the header/footer section of the properties box

Comment: I see what you mean now. But, this usually doesn't work well e.g. when your document content is longer then one page you have the footer only on last page.

Comment: OK, then you would need to think out of the box, for example :

Comment: - export data to XML
- transform it to a nice HTML using XSLT

or

- using Apache POI, generate a nice PDF

or

- generate a temporary document on the fly, controling the layout with the various methods of the RichTextItem class

Comment: Another problem is that even if you don't use the text based header and footer, Notes creates a 1inch margin at the top and bottom. Is there a way to have this reduced ?